# Unable to deploy Django/Docker/Nginx/Gunicorn/Celery/RabbitMQ/SSL on AWS Lightsail

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx

I have been trying for more than a week few hours daily.

Needless to say, I'm beginner in most of these things, but I have tried hundreds of configurations and nothing worked.

That's why I am finally coming here for help.

I am currently getting 502 Bad Gateway.

My suspicion is that either Nginx can't find staticfiles (if that's a reason for a 50x error) or nginx upstream doesn't know what is web (in config), or something with permissions on nginx.

Nginx error logs are printing this:

> connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream...upstream: "https://some-ip-address-here?:443" (this might be that nginx doesn't know about the web)

**Dockerfile**

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.10.2-slim-bullseye

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Create and set work directory called `app`
RUN mkdir -p /app
RUN mkdir -p /app/staticfiles
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt

RUN set -ex && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y upgrade && \
    apt-get install -y ffmpeg && \
    rm -rf /root/.cache/ 

# Copy local project
COPY . /app/
COPY wait-for-it.sh /wait-for-it.sh
RUN chmod +x /wait-for-it.sh
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    build: .
    restart: always
    command: ["/wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "--workers", "3", "my_project.wsgi"]
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "443"
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - db
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    image: jonasal/nginx-certbot:4.2.0-nginx1.23.3
    env_file:
      - .env.nginx
    volumes:
      - nginx_secrets:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./nginx/user_conf.d:/etc/nginx/user_conf.d
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    depends_on:
      - web
      - db
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file: .env
  celery:
    container_name: celery
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
    command: celery -A my_project worker -l info -B 
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - web
      - rabbitmq3
  rabbitmq3:
    container_name: rabbitmq
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  nginx_secrets:
```

**Nginx config**

```
upstream web {
    server web:443;
}

# Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myurl.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

    location /static/ {
        alias /app/staticfiles/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /app/media/;
    }

}

# Pass request to the web container
server {    

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://web/;
    }    

    access_log /var/log/nginx/project.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/project.error.log;
    
    # Listen to port 443 on both IPv4 and IPv6.
    listen 443 ssl default_server reuseport;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server reuseport;
    server_name www.myurl.com myurl.com;
    
    # Load the certificate files
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-site/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-site/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-site/chain.pem;

    # Load the Diffie-Hellman parameter
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/dhparams/dhparam.pem;

    location /static/ {
        alias /app/staticfiles/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /app/media/;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you create the docker image locally, and run it locally without any issues?

Comment: It's working. I am not really sure if nginx is really working as it's not printing anything out, only web does (maybe this doesn't matter at all), but the site loads. Does that perhaps mean that my domain settings are wrong? I have a custom domain outside of AWS which I'm pointing to my instance (but I have another site that works and have done exactly the same things)

Comment: What is working specifically? If you run `docker-compose up` locally, and you can load a web page at `http://localhost` and `https://localhost` then nginx would definitely be working.

Comment: So actually there is some problem (same one I had on AWS servers).I used `127.0.0.1:8000`. Going to `http://localhost` immediately redirects to `https://localhost` and this doesn't even load the page - I get this error: Secure Connection Failed - An error occurred during a connection to localhost. PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR

Comment: `localhost:8000` loads the page (but I had to change nginx image to one without certbot because It was throwing an error that localhost can't get SSL, so I also changed much of the config just to http). I am really confused from how this all works, I will do some studying on nginx, but it's impossible to debug when each time I need to do so many  changes. It must be something with nginx though and SSL